How to create a custom button in a tooltip when hovering over an email in Gmail

GitLab for example has this fancy View merge request button and Unsubscribe button when you just hovering letter in gmail, i wonder how can i create similar button
I want to add simmilar buttons for my email, no idea what to search or how to create something like this

Hi there. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more information about asking good questions on StackOverflow. To get started, right-click the button and select "Inspect" or hit <F12> and go from there.

These are called Gmail Actions. You can check out Google’s documentation here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/actions-overview
It’s basically a JSON-LD script element that you add to the <head> of your HTML email. For example:
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "ViewAction",
    "url": "https://www.example.com",
    "name": "View Merge request"
  },
  "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
}
</script>

